# Maximum Monthly Temperature Reducer code

Tags: mapreduce

```
package com.ibm.dw61;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class MaxTempReducer extends
     Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

   public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
              throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       int maxTemp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
       for (IntWritable value: values) {
       maxTemp = Math.max(maxTemp, value.get());
       }
       context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxTemp));

   }
}
```

Questions :

1) int maxTemp = Integer.MIN_VALUE   <----- this line seems to be a initialisation of the maxTemp variable. Why does the coder not initialise it to zero? Integer.MIN_VALUE gives -2147483648. It is impossible for lowest temperature to ever reach -100 degrees.

2) context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxTemp)   <------ This is the end result. Key is month and maxTemp is the maximum temperature for the month. Why does the 'new' word required for maxTemp but not for the key (month)?

Answer (score 0):

**1) int maxTemp = Integer.MIN_VALUE**

> public static final int MIN_VALUE
>
> > A constant holding the minimum value
> >     an int can have, -231.

**2) context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxTemp)**

[Why does Hadoop need classes like Text or IntWritable instead of String or Integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441055/why-does-hadoop-need-classes-like-text-or-intwritable-instead-of-string-or-integ)

Hope this is helpful